# Select a column based on another column's value with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

With a Pandas dataframe structured as follows:

```
              color    price_blue   price_red   price_green
date
2019-01-01    green            10          20            30
2019-01-02      red            40          50            60
2019-01-03     blue            11          12            13
```

How can we add a `price` column based on the value of the `color` column for each row:

```
              color    price_blue   price_red   price_green    price
date
2019-01-01    green            10          20            30       30
2019-01-02      red            40          50            60       50
2019-01-03     blue            11          12            13       11
```

Although an `apply`-like solution seems easy enough, in this case a vectorised solution is needed as the dataset is relatively large.

In addition, solutions like `np.where` work fine with only a few color choices, however in the real case there are more than 20 different "colors", so that would end up quite impractical with a lot of nested `where`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with add `price_` to column `color` for match by columns names:

```
df['price'] = df.lookup(df.index, 'price_' + df['color'])
print (df)
            color  price_blue  price_red  price_green  price
2019-01-01  green          10         20           30     30
2019-01-02    red          40         50           60     50
2019-01-03   blue          11         12           13     11
```